# How to sign request object and send request?

Tags: node.js, node-request, node-fetch

i am using nodejs with `node-fetch` library to send a requests and `node-http-signature` package for sign request.  Node-fetch has only one method to send request `fetch()`.  How can i create request object, than pass this object to `sign()` method from `node-http-signature` package and then send this signed request using `fetch()` method?

I would be grateful for some sample code.